# Controlling JSLint from Maven (javascript-maven-plugin)

Tags: javascript, maven

Is there a way to control JSLint execution from the pom.xml when using javascript-maven-plugin?

While I find this plugin otherwise very useful, the JSLint execution seems very strict and I have not found any way of bypassing it.

I'm using the Aptana Studio plugin for Eclipse, which also validates the code using JSLint, but it allows ignoring certaing "errors", like not finding the 'console'.